# How to write lambda for array inside list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

```
public class A
{
    private B[] b;
    //getter setter
}

public class B
{
    private String id;
    //getter setter
}
```

I already got A object from stream as shown below but can't find way to complete this lambda to get List of ids which is inside B class.

```
Stream <String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.json"));
lines.map(x -> (A)gson.fromJson(x, type))...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `flatMap` here:

```
 lines.map(x -> (A)gson.fromJson(x, type))
      .flatMap(y -> Arrays.stream(y.getB()))
      .map(B::getId)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet())  // or any other terminal operation
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `flatMap`:

```
 lines.map(x -> (A)gson.fromJson(x, type)).flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a.getB())
```

Now it's a `Stream<B>`; you can map that to their Ids now

```
    .map(B::getId)
```

and make a list out of this.

```
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The OP wants a List with B's Id
`List<String> bId lines.map(x -> (A)gson.fromJson(x, type)).flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a.getB()).map(B::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera You're right. I updated my answer.